# Moq.Times parameter default value? how to create a struct constant, bc Moq.Times.Once() is not a compile time constant

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq

I have a parameter that is of type Moq.Times and I want it to have a default value of Moq.Times.Once() except Once() is a method and not a compile time constant.

So I set made the parameter nullable and set the default value to null and then in the method, if the param value is null, I set it to / invoke Moq.Times.Once() and that's fine, but what I'd really like to do is have a default value of Moq.Times.Once()

Is there a more clever / simpler way to do this?

What I want but doesn't compile:

```
void MyMethod(Moq.Times invocationTimes = Moq.Time.Once()) { ... }
```

What I do instead:

```
void MyMethod(Moq.Times? invocationTimes = null) { if (invocationTimes == null) { invocationTimes = Times.Once(); }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should allow `null` and then replace that at runtime.

You can make your code a bit more [concise with the null coalescing operator since C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator):

```cs
void MyMethod(Moq.Times? invocationTimes = null) 
{ 
    invocationTimes ??= Times.Once(); 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Very clever. Dude I'm definitely going to use that null coalescing operator, I've written if (x==null) { x = something; } about a million times. Thanks!